# Facebook messenger bot quick reply with image_url only not working

Tags: facebook, chatbot, messenger

I created my nodejs facebook messenger chatbot and everything is working fine, except quick replies with images only.

according to the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies):

> You may also send a quick reply with an image and an empty title string to create an icon-only quick reply.

When I send an image with the *title* attribute I get the quick reply prepended with the image correctly, however when I put an empty string in the *title* attribute to show an "Only-icon" quick reply, it doesn't work.

**JSON that works:**

```
{
    "content_type": "text",
    "title": 'Any text here',
    "payload": '',
    "image_url": "Link/To/Img"
}
```

**JSON that doesn't work:**

```
{
    "content_type": "text",
    "title": '',                // (Change is here) Empty title
    "payload": '',
    "image_url": "Link/To/Img"
}
```

I have been stuck for hours in this matter, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I just tested it and this works for me. What error message do you receive from Facebook?

Comment: It doesn't show any error message, it just doesn't show the picture if the title is empty. for instance, if the title is just ' ' (space characted) the image will show with a right empty space margin, but if the title is empty string the image disappears and the whole button becomes visually empty!

Comment: Ok when I send a quick reply with an empty title string it looks like a space is added to the right of the image. This seems to be the default behaviour for me. Not sure why yours would be different.